# How to use tf.metrics correctly?

Tags: tensorflow

I was using the following code to evaluate precision and recall of the model.
both Z3 and Y's shape are (1,?)

```
predictions = tf.greater(Z3, 0.0)
labels = tf.greater(Y, 0.5)

true_positive = tf.logical_and(predictions, labels)
precision = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((true_positive), tf.float32)) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((predictions), tf.float32))
recall = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((true_positive), tf.float32)) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((labels), tf.float32))
```

The code above works, but when I switch to the code below, it does not work.

```
labels = tf.greater(Y, 0.5)
predictions = tf.greater(Z3, 0.0)

auc = tf.metrics.auc(labels, predictions)
precisions = tf.metrics.precision(labels, predictions)
recalls = tf.metrics.recall(labels, predictions)

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): tags and values not the same shape: [] != [2] (tag 'recalls')
 [[Node: recalls = ScalarSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](recalls/tags, recalls/values)]]
```

It seems that the shape are different, but when I print those, both show (1,?).

Are there any ways to find out the shape of these two tensors when they run, or fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.metrics.precision` and `tf.metrics.recall` return 2 values, a `precision` Tensor (`recall` respectively) and a `update_op` Operation (see documentation of [tf.metrics.precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/precision)). You are assigning both to a single variable.